# how to insert into type in postgresql type

Tags: types, insert, postgresql-9.4

I have a table type newIntList

```
CREATE TYPE newIntList AS
(
    id bigint
);
```

want to insert a  integer value into the type variable.

Tried below code ,not working....

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertintoType(n1 integer) 
    RETURNS table(id integer) AS $$
    declare
    list newIntList[];
    BEGIN
    
    insert into list
    select n1;    //looking for a code for inserting into Type "**newIntList**"
    
    
    return query 
    select unnest(list );
    END; $$
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Please help

Comment: The type seems completely useless in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a "type instance", you need to use a [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

To put an element into an array, just [assign](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) it, you don't use `insert` for that.

Also the type of the returned `id` column doesn't match - it must be `bigint` to match the column in the type.

Your final select isn't matching the definition of your function's result. `unnest(list)` will return a single column of of type `newintlist`, not an integer (or bigint). You need to use `select * from unnest(...)` to achieve that.

So the function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertintoType(n1 integer) 
  RETURNS table(id bigint) --<< match the data type in newintlist
AS $$
declare
  list newintlist[];
BEGIN
  list[0] := row(n1); --<< create a new "instance" of the type and assign it to the first element
  
  return query 
    select * 
    from unnest(list) as l(id);
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select *
from insertintotype(1);
```

---

But I fail to see why you don't just use an integer or bigint array inside the function. The custom type seems useless.

Comment: can you please  help for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668798/how-to-pass-a-type-as-an-input-variable-to-a-inner-function-which-is-called-in-a      @a_horse_with_no_name